# Is filtering questions by tag wildcard broken or changed somehow?

Tags: support, bug, tags, wildcards

When I filter questions for example by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity* and select the "newest" question tab and 50 questions per page right now the last question on the first page is "asked Mar 6 at 23:11". (Today is March 14 and the bunch of tags selected with the wildcard isn't that inactive normally.)

Selecting only one of all those tags (which should just be a subset of the wildcard url) by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework the last question on the page is "asked yesterday".

Is there a problem with the wildcard search or some other bug? Until yesterday it worked as expected for me.

**Edit**

It might be a sorting problem. The number of pages looks correct. However, at the moment page 3 for example ends with a question "asked Jul 20 '11" ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity*?page=3&sort=newest&pagesize=50

...while page 4 starts with a question "asked 19 hours ago":

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity*?page=4&sort=newest&pagesize=50

**Edit 2**

Another example: On this page 6...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc*?page=6&sort=newest&pagesize=50

...hundreds of questions about ASP.NET MVC are missing (or the "newest" sort order is somehow different than it used to be):

[image: Newest questions]

No new questions about ASP.NET MVC(*) for 11 days?

Comment: Seems to work as expected for me, just tried the examples...

Comment: Works fine for me; when you go to a `tagged/entity*` URL the wildcard is expanded into all the matching tags anyway. Clicking on the link you provided, I see 32k questions.

Comment: Make sure you selected the correct tab at the top (not 'Unanswered' for example).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, the wildcard is expanded, but the result is wrong. For example: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389751/update-datase-error-in-entity-framework) is not on the first page when using the "entity*" wildcard filter, but on the first page when using the "entity-framework" filter. Both with "newest" tag selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared yesterday. Using tag wildcards works fine again.